# Connecting to Oracle using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess Nuget Package Version 12.1.022 in my C# (.NET 4.0) project. The package automatically creates entries in the app.config file. How can I read the datasource string from this file to be able to connect to the data base?

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("dataSource");

is not working for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
             type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
           description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
           type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="MyDataSource"
                    descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=100.100.100.100)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myservice.com)))" />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There's a dedicated ConnectionStrings section in configuration files for storing connection strings, move your entry there and then use ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Typically, you would refer to the alias in a standard connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MyDataSource;User Id=scott;Password=tiger;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then you would use the standard method for retrieving the string:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Also keep in mind that the alias in the data source section is optional.  You can embed the descriptor directly in the connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=100.100.100.100)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myservice.com)));User Id=scott;Password=tiger;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

You can also refer to aliases in a tnsnames.ora file.  By default the driver looks for a tnsnames.ora in the exe folder, a directory specified in a TNS_ADMIN environment variable, or the TNS_ADMIN config variable:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e41125/featConfig.htm#autoId6
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e41125/featConfig.htm#autoId7

Comment: Thanks so much.  This is the BEST explanation I've seen of how all the parts fit together.  The DATA SOURCE part of this solved my problem after days of having people smarter than me staring at my computer and getting nowhere.

Answer (score 8):

You can refer to the already defined datasource in the connection string

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
        <dataSources>
            <dataSource alias="MyDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=100.100.100.100)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myservice.com)))" />
        </dataSources>
    </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

for instance, in this specific case:

```
public class OracleDBManager
{
    private OracleConnection _con;
    private const string connectionString = "User Id={0};Password={1};Data Source=MyDataSource;";
    private const string OracleDBUser = "exampleUser";
    private const string OracleDBPassword = "examplePassword";

    public OracleDBManager()
    {
        InitializeDBConnection();
    }

    ~OracleDBManager()
    {
        if (_con != null)
        {
            _con.Close();
            _con.Dispose();
            _con = null;
        }
    }

    private void InitializeDBConnection()
    {
            _con = new OracleConnection();
            _con.ConnectionString = string.Format(connectionString, OracleDBUser, OracleDBPassword);
            _con.Open();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a separate class file returning the connectionstring like this -

```
public class OracleDbConnection
{
 public static OracleConnection GetConnection()
 {
  const string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PROD))); User Id=userId;Password=password;";
  var connection=new OracleConnection(connectionString);
  return connection;
 }
}
```

Then you can call it like this where you need to access oracle db-

```
var oracleConnection = OracleDbConnection.GetConnection();
oracleConnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the package [Formo](https://github.com/ChrisMissal/Formo), I created following method to get the `MyDataSource` string from `app.config` file

```
using Configuration = Formo.Configuration;
.......
/// <summary>
/// Gets the data source from app.config file
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public string GetMyDataSource()
{
    dynamic config = new Configuration();
    return config.MyDataSource;
}
```