# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied when trying to connect via ODP.NET (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client)

Tags: oracle, odp.net, ora-01017

Following code throws: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

```
string constr = "User Id=Name;Password=Password;Data Source=server:1521/service";
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
con.Open();
```

SQL Developer, DBeaver connects without problems.
FIPS is disabled.

System:

- Oracle Server 11g (11.2.0.3.0)
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 19.6.0
- .Net Framework 4.8
- Windows 10 1909

I would be very thankful for any help!

Comment: A connection by the deprecated "System.Data.OracleClient" namespace works also without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the password is correct (no offense, but 99.99% of the time, this error is because the password is wrong), one possible cause of this issue is case sensitivity and different password hash algorithms.

If you create a user with the password "PASSWORD", Oracle may create multiple different password hashes for it.  One of the versions, meant to work with old clients, will work with either "PASSWORD" or "password".  The newer version will only work with "PASSWORD".  So you might be *always* using the wrong password, you're just getting lucky with the old client.

Oracle password hashes are a real mess.  You can check things like the columns SYS.USER$.PASSWORD and SYS.USER$.SPARE4 for the hashes, or the SQLNET.ORA file for parameters meant to disable certain hashes.  But most of the time you're better off just re-creating the password and seeing if that works.

(And if this is indeed the case, don't learn the wrong lesson and try to disable old password hash algorithms.  It is much harder than the manual implies.)

Comment: I already changed my password > 10 times.
All variations lowercase/uppercase/numbers only ...

Comment: I think, this is odac compatibility issue. We have odac 12.x and it works with 11.2 and 12.2

Comment: I just had the same issue in Dbeaver, and the issue was that the password was considered case insensitive (by default), while uppercase matters in my case..

Answer (score -1):

I don' think that is a valid data source descriptor for ODP.net.  See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31592492/852208

Edited: It looks like you are using the ezconnect format, but that requires the username and password to be inline:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/using-the-easy-connect-naming-method-aka-ez-connect/

Comment: If the descripter is invalid, you definitly get another error.

Comment: definitely?  the closest thing I could find to what you are doing is the ezconnect format, but I see no option for not specifying username and password in that format:
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT

Comment: more:https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/using-the-easy-connect-naming-method-aka-ez-connect/